# Constructing an indescernible sequence from a coheir

Tags: logic, model-theory

What follows is part of Exercise 1.34 from Pillay's *Introduction to Stability Theory*.  Suppose the following:

1. $M \prec N$.
2. $N$ is $|M|^+$-saturated.
3. $p \in S_1(M)$, $q \in S_1(N)$.
4. $q \supset p$ is a coheir of $p$.

Construct a sequence $(a_i \mid i  < \omega)$ of elements in $N$ inductively as follows: let $a_0$ realize $p$, and given $a_0, \dots, a_n$, let $a_{n+1}$ realize $q \upharpoonright Ma_0\dots a_n$.  The exercise is to show that $(a_i)_i$ is an indiscernible sequence over $M$.

My attempt is to show, by induction on $n$, that for $\bar ab$ and $\bar a'b'$, subsequences of $(a_i)_i$ of length $n$, the type of $\bar a$ over $M$ is the same as that of $\bar a'$.  Suppose that the following are equivalent for a formula $\phi$ without parameters, $\bar cd $ a subsequence of $(a_i)_i$, and $\bar m \in M$:

1. $N \models \phi(\bar c, d; \bar m)$
2. There exists $d' \in M$ such that $N \models \phi(\bar c, d';\bar m)$.

Note that since $q$ is a coheir, 1 implies 2.  If that is true, what I need to prove is a straightforward consequence of the induction hypothesis.

My question is whether or not the two conditions are equivalent, and how to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no hope that your condition $2$ implies your condition $1$. For example, imagine that $\varphi$ has just one free variable, so the implication reduces to "if there exists $d'\in M$ such that $N\models \varphi(d')$, then $N\models \varphi(d)$." Unless $T$ proves that $\varphi$ is true of everything or false of everything, there are going to be elements of $M$ that satisfy $\varphi$ and elements of $M$ that satisfy $\lnot\varphi$, so if $2$ implies $1$, $d$ has to satisfy both $\varphi$ and $\lnot\varphi$.

---

I'll spell out the approach hinted at by Levon's answer and by me in the comments to Levon's answer. The key property of coheirs is that they are *invariant types*.

We say that $q(x)\in S_1(N)$ is *$M$-invariant* if for every formula $\psi(x,y)$ and all tuples $b, b'\in N$, if $\mathrm{tp}(b/M) = \mathrm{tp}(b'/M)$, then $\psi(x,b)\in q(x)\iff \psi(x,b')\in q(x)$.

**Claim:** If $q(x)$ is a coheir of its restriction to $M$, then it is $M$-invariant.

**Proof:** Suppose not. Then there is a formula $\psi(x,y)$ and tuples $b,b'\in N$ such that $\mathrm{tp}(b/M) = \mathrm{tp}(b'/M)$, $\psi(x,b)\in q(x)$, and $\psi(x,b')\notin q(x)$. Hence $\psi(x,b)\land \lnot\psi(x,b')\in q(x)$. But since $q(x)$ is a coheir of its restriction to $M$, there exists $a\in M$ such that $N\models \psi(a,b)\land \lnot\psi(a,b')$. This contradicts our assumption that $\mathrm{tp}(b/M) = \mathrm{tp}(b'/M)$. $\square$

Now forget the fact that $q$ is a coheir and just remember that it's $M$-invariant. Build a sequence as described in your question (this is called a *Morley sequence* for the invariant type $q$). To show that it's $M$-indiscernible, show by induction on $n$ that $\mathrm{tp}(\overline{a}b/M) = \mathrm{tp}(\overline{a}'b'/M)$ whenever $\overline{a}b$ and $\overline{a}'b'$ are subsequences of length $n+1$. And note that this amounts to showing that for any formula $\psi$, $\psi(x,\overline{a},\overline{m})\in \mathrm{tp}(b/M\overline{a}) = q\restriction M\overline{a}$ if and only if $\psi(x,\overline{a}',\overline{m})\in \mathrm{tp}(b'/M\overline{a}') = q\restriction M\overline{a}'$.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think 2 implies 1 as stated.

My hint for the exercise would be the following: let $\phi(\bar x, y)$ be a formula over $M$ and let $\bar a'' \in N$ realise the type $tp(\bar a/M) = tp(\bar a'/M)$. Show that $\phi(\bar a, b)$ iff $\phi(\bar a'', x) \in q$ iff $\phi(\bar a', b')$.

Comment: Thank you.   How about this: $\models \phi(\bar a, b)$ iff $\phi(\bar a, x) \in q$ iff $\phi(\bar a'', x) \in q$, the second equivalence following from the existence of an automorphism of $N$ over $M$ that extends the bijection $\bar a \cong \bar a'$.  But I didn't use the fact that $q$ is a coheir!  I can't think of how to use this hypothesis except as in my original post...

Comment: Why should the second equivalence follow from the existence of that automorphism? What you're using here is that $q$ is an *$M$-invariant type*, i.e. that if $\text{tp}(b/M) = \text{tp}(b'/M)$, then $\psi(x,b)\in q$ if and only if $\psi(x,b')\in q$. Not every type over $N$ is $M$-invariant, but every coheir is!

Comment: In addition to what Alex says. Firstly $\bar a \not \in N$. So $\phi(\bar a, x) \in q$ is not defined. What you want instead is $\phi(\bar a, x) \in q|_{N\bar a}$. Now think of how you define $q|_{N\bar a}$.

Comment: @LevonHaykazyan Thank you for your continued attention to my post.  I thought $\bar a$ _was_ in $N$ by construction...

Comment: @AlexKruckman  That makes sense.  And to show that $q$ is $M$-invariant, well, I can't think of anything other than the flawed equivalence in my original post!  An alternative may be $\psi(x,  b) \in q$ iff there is $m \in M$ such that $\psi(m, b)$ (i.e., the formula does not have to be finitely satisfied by an element in $N$), but I'm not sure there is a big difference between this and what I originally had in mind.

Comment: @Pteromys You are right, my bad. I misread the question. I thought $a_n$ lives in a monster model and realises $q|_{Na_0...a_{n-1}}$, which is the unique extension of $q$ to a type over $Na_0...a_{n-1}$ which coinherits from $M$. For your situation, while my hint is still correct, Alex's approach is the one to go for.